# Porque as vezes, quando adicionamos imagens em uma página, se passar o mouse sobre ela, ela se mexe?

Tags: html, css

Porque as vezes quando adicionamos algumas imagens em uma página, algumas se mexem e já outras não? **Isso é um problema** dos navegadores? Ou o problema deve estar no `CSS`?

Por que "raios" quando passa o mouse por cima da imagem ela se mexe?

[**VEJA O SITE**](http://theme-sphere.com/smart-mag/)

> Passe o mouse sobre a imagem da notícia `Make The Perfect Dessert in Ten Mins` (em baixo do slider).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao passar o mouse, note que a imagem se mexe, ela sai do esquadro. Já a notícia ao lado dela `Premiere for The Invisible Woman` ao passar o mouse sobre a imagem da mulher, não ocorre isso.

Percebi também pela ferramenta `Inspecionar Elemento` do **Google Chrome** que desativando alguma propriedades como:

```
.wp-post-image:hover {opacity:0.8}
.appear {-webkit-transition:all .4s ease-in-out}
```

Esse problema acaba, só que eu perco os efeitos.

Comment: É problema no teu CSS. Verifica se não tens nenhuma propriedade aplicada nas imagens

Comment: Olha esse site: http://theme-sphere.com/smart-mag/
Agora passe o mouse em cima da imagem da notícia `Make The Perfect Dessert in Ten Mins` em baixo do slider. (Utilize o Chrome)

Comment: Sim, isso é um efeito css aplicado na imagem

Comment: Ahhh é verdade, o problema é o `opacity` com o `-webkit-transition` no `:hover` (acabei de testar). Mas como resolver isso? Não quero ter que remover os efeitos.

Comment: Então deixa ver se percebi... Queres umas imagens com aquele efeito, e queres outras sem os efeitos, é isso?

Comment: Não! Só quero corrigir esse problema ao passar o mouse.

Comment: Se não queres remover os efeitos queres o que? Tirar os efeitos apenas quando passa o rato? Assim nunca vai produzir o efeito de desfocar a imagem... lol já não estou a entender nada...

Comment: Eu não quero remover nada, absolutamente nada! Só quero alguma maneira de acabar com esse mini bug. Ele só acaba se eu desativar o `opacity` ou o `-webkit-transition` no `:hover`, mas não quero fazer isso. Só queria alguma solução que acabasse com esse problema.

Comment: Não está nada claro o que estás a perguntar. Bug? Mas que bug? Coloca o teu CSS na pergunta e esclarece melhor o teu problema

Comment: Meu jovem, basta entrar no link que lhe enviei e você verá que ao passar o mouse sobre a segunda imagem na notícia abaixo do slider se mexe quando passa o mouse em cima.

Comment: Não queres por não pões, depois admira-te da pergunta ser fechada

Comment: Porque fica votando para fechar minha pergunta? Não tenho culpa se não sabe utilizar a ferramenta do Chrome `Inspecionar Elemento` basta fazer isso na imagem e você verá todas as classes e propriedades do elemento inspecionado. Teste-o.

Comment: Esse site não é meu.

Comment: Sua pergunta não está sendo objetiva. Pelo que compreendi, a sua aplicação está fazendo o mesmo que o site que demonstrou, certo? Se sim, considere adicionar as linhas de código referente ao seu problema. 
Se você esta apenas inspecionando uma página de um terceiro e tentando entender algo, seja claro! Demonstre com uma imagem por exemplo.

Comment: Eu testei com Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari e IE, e em nenhum deles a imagem que você referiu se mexia.

Comment: @Math só quando passa ou mouse por cima.

Comment: @AlexandreLopes eu passei, exatamente na imagem que você acabou de adicionar, e passei no da mulher do lado, e não ocorreu o erro que você citou em nenhuma das duas imagens, apenas o efeito que era para acontecer. Qual browser utilizou?

Comment: Utilizei o Google Chrome (Ultima Versão), e utilizei o Firefox, só que nele (Firefox) ao invés de mexer quando passa o mouse, a imagem fica maior do que é pra ser, cerca de 1px.

Answer (score 2):

Vamos lá, vou responder a base do que eu entendi.
A imagem do `Slider` recebeu um efeito de zoom, aumentando a escala no `:hover`.

Basicamente a imagem recebe um zoom dentro da div, digamos. 
Se você inspecionar o elemento e remover as seguintes linhas do css:

```
/* image zoom effect */
.main-featured .slides .image-link, .main-featured .blocks .image-link {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;

    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Você vai notar que agora a imagem irá crescer e de fato, sair do esquadro.
Agora vamos para a segunda parte.

O efeito de zoom interno é dado por esse código:

```
.main-featured .blocks article:hover img, .main-featured .slides .flex-active-slide:hover img { 

    /* fix flicker and use hardware acceleration */
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-perspective: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(0.1deg);  /* firefox flicker fix */

    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Portanto, removendo essas linhas você remove esse efeito.

@edit

Me baseando na imagem que passou, tentei testar e ver se encontrava alguma movimentação mas não consegui. A única coisa que vejo sendo usado no `:hover` é a propriedade `opacity` que define a transparência.

[image: Antes e depois do :hover]

Comment: Você entendeu errado, rsrs... Não é o slider e sim a imagem da notícia abaixo do slider. Vou colocar uma imagem para você ver.

Comment: Mesmo assim obrigado por tentar ajudar!